# why use array($this,'function') instead of $this->function()

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, class

I was checking out a WordPress plugin and I saw this function in the constructor of a class:

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'function_name'));
```

I searched and found that `array($this, 'function_name')` is a valid callback. What I don't understand is: why use this method, instead of using `$this->function_name();`

Here's a sample code:

```
class Hello{
  function __construct(){
    add_action('init', array($this, 'printHello'));
  }
  function printHello(){
    echo 'Hello';
  }
}
$t = new Hello;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your sample code, `$this->printHello()` will not work outside of your `class Hello`. Passing a reference to the current object ($this) and the name of a method will allow the external code to call the given method of your object.